# Pandas condition on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

My goal is to properly select all Rows where the relevant columns (dynamically as list) meet specific conditions:

| A | Br |
| --- | --- |
| * | * |
| None | None |
| Test | * |

I can easily select the rows (dynamically) where the relevant columns are None/NaN etc with:

```
df[['A', 'B']].isna().all(1)
```

If I try the same approach with for example: * my method fails miserably:

```
df[df[['A', 'B']]=='*'].all(1)
```

This return every row as True like I would expect from the 'any' keyword??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need test boolean DataFrame:

```
m = (df[['A', 'B']]=='*').all(1)
```

Or:

```
m = df[['A', 'B']].eq('*').all(1)
```